# SKSpriteNode Collision Removal In Removing Wrong One With Xcode Swift SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am making a game where when the character lands on the cloud, the cloud fades out.  I put in code to determine when it is hit, there are multiple clouds registered under the same SKSpriteNode, but when it lands on the cloud, the wrong cloud is fading away, it is the most recently added SKSpriteNode that is being removed, not the one it is colliding with.

Is there any way to do it so it only removes the one that the character has collided with, not the earliest one that spawns?  Here is the code:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact)
{



    let contactMask = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask

    switch(contactMask)
    {





    case BodyType.PersonCategory.rawValue | BodyType.CloudCategory.rawValue:

        let CheckDelay = delay(0.02)
            {

                    self.Cloud.runAction(self.FadeAway)

        }

    default:
        return





Person.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
Person.size = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width / 25, self.frame.size.height / 16.25)
Person.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: Person.size)
Person.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
Person.physicsBody?.friction = 0
Person.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
Person.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
Person.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
Person.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
Person.zPosition = 5
Person.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyType.PersonCategory.rawValue
Person.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.CloudCategory.rawValue
Person.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) * 1.7)
self.addChild(Person)


Cloud = SKSpriteNode(texture: NormalCloudTexture)
Cloud.zPosition = 7
Cloud.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
Cloud.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
Cloud.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
Cloud.size = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width / 8.05, self.frame.size.height / 40)
Cloud.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: Cloud.size)
Cloud.physicsBody?.friction = 0
Cloud.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
Cloud.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
Cloud.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) / 7.60)
addChild(Cloud)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the cloud represented by the physicsBody actually making the contact. so bodyA is either the player, or the cloud, and then bodyB is either the player or the cloud. Then get the actual SKSpriteNode from the physics body. It can be referenced via the node property on the SKPhysics body. So either bodyA.node, or bodyB.node.

Comment: how would I go about doing that, I was not so sure.  This is the code I use when I declare the character and the cloud for their physics body

Comment: Cloud = SKSpriteNode(texture: NormalCloudTexture)
    Cloud.zPosition = 7
    Cloud.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    Cloud.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    Cloud.size = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width / 8.05, self.frame.size.height / 40)
    Cloud.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: Cloud.size)
    Cloud.physicsBody?.friction = 0
    Cloud.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    Cloud.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) / 7.60)
    addChild(Cloud)

Comment: I put the code in the question as it did not fit in here if you are able to look at it.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you have up there, have you named your instances with Caps? Are you saying you have multiple clouds, but you just keep assigning the new clouds into the same cloud pointer?

Comment: Yes, I named my instances with caps, should I remove that?  And yes, I have multiple clouds that I am assigning to the same cloud pointer, is that a no go?   Should I get several different ones instead?

Comment: It sounds like you might be confused about how references and pointers work. When you create ten cloud in a row, assigning each one to the same variable, ie "Cloud", then only the last one you create will be referenced by the variable "Cloud". You just need to follow my instructions to pull the correct cloud node out of the physics bodies.